# Navigation Bar shows as black Xcode 7 Beta 5

Tags: xcode, navigation, beta

Navigation Bar for a project is not showing. Below is a screen shot of the running and the design pages. I tried cleaning the project and deleting the derived data to no avail.

There is an error message, probably the bar is never being created? What happened, any ideas? The project is empty.

[image]

After embedding navigation controller:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is 'Login' viewcontroller your initial view controller. if it is, create navigation controller and make it initial view controller, and make 'Login' to its rootviewcontroller.

And for the blank spaces at the top and bottom, create an image at 640 x 1136 pixel size and add it to your splash images.

Comment: Stupid of me to forget about the Navigation Controller. I used Editor->Embed In->Navigation Controller. However that did not work either. So I deleted everything from the storyboard, deleted the embedded data, and created the windows from scratch.  However, still not working.  Added second screenshot to the original question. I have; however, created a blank project and everything just works fine.